# How to find matrices with given commutation relation?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups

Suppose the matrices $\alpha, \beta$ with the given commutating relations:

$$
\alpha^2=a I\\
    \beta^2=b I\\
    \alpha\beta=c I\\
    \beta\alpha=d I
$$

where $a,b,c,d $ are elements of $\mathbb{R}$ and where $I$ is the identity matrix.

How can I find specific examples of $\alpha, \beta$, or even solve for the general case?

Comment: $\frac1c\alpha\cdot\beta=I\Rightarrow \frac1c\alpha=\beta^{-1}\Rightarrow \beta\cdot\frac1c\alpha=I\Rightarrow c=d.$

Comment: @minz I am actually fine with $c=d$, but I cannot afford $a=b$. Can we say that $a$ is not necessarily equal to $b$?

Comment: surely. Consider $\alpha =I, \beta=2I$ then $\alpha^2 =I, \beta^2=4I, \alpha \beta= \beta\alpha =2I $

Comment: @minz, my apologies, what I am looking for is actually a matrice where a, b and c are independent of each other. c and d can be equal this is fine.